# Timestep error for Logistic Map in LTSPICE

Tags: components, simulation, ltspice, non-linear

I am building a logistic map circuit in LTSPICE. So far, I've prepared this:
[image]

The factor of 25 after the second AD633 is for increasing the scope of the parameter values. However, this circuit always gives me timestep error. I have tried changing the solver to alternate, changing Gmin values, etc. I checked every part of the circuit individually and they seem to work well.
[image]

I checked the voltage values just after the second sample and hold. They are going in Megavolts. I am guessing the sample and hold isn't properly configured or isn't working as it should, leading to non-convergence.

Netlist:

`R1 N010 N009 1k
V1 N009 0 10
R2 N001 N003 1k
R3 N002 N001 1k
V3 P001 0 12
V4 0 P002 12
R4 N010 0 1k
XU1 N010 N001 P001 P002 N002 TL071
XU2 N002 0 N003 0 P003 0 N005 P004 AD633
V2 P004 0 15
V5 0 P003 15
XU3 N005 N008 P005 P006 N007 TL071
R5 N008 0 1k
R6 N007 N008 3k
V7 0 P006 15
V8 P005 0 15
XU4 N004 0 N007 0 P007 0 N006 P008 AD633
V9 P008 0 15
V10 0 P007 15
V6 N004 0 8
A1 N006 0 N011 0 0 0 N013 0 SAMPLEHOLD
V11 N011 0 PULSE(0 1 0 1u 1u 0.5 1)
A2 N013 0 N012 0 0 0 N003 0 SAMPLEHOLD
V12 N012 0 PULSE(1 0 0 1u 1u 0.5 1)
.tran 10
.lib ..\sym\EXTRA\AudioOpamp\TI\TL071.301
.lib AD633.SUB
.backanno
.end`

Any help with this is appreciated. Thank You!

**Edit:** I tried using AD633 with high frequency (100Hz) sine wave, and it gave me timestep error. I think that's what's causing problems. It worked well only at a frequency of 0.01Hz. What's the get around to this? Is the AD633 faulty?

Comment: Try shunting things to gnd with high impedance

Comment: Wow really small impossible to read schematics.

Comment: Your netlist is only the visible one. The hidden information is where things, most likely, go wrong, such as the device models. You can also try adding `Rser=1m` (and/or `Cpar=1m` or so) to your supply voltages, and you can re-use the same clock for the sampling, no need for two identical. Also, that clock can be sped up like this: `pulse 0 1 0 1u 0 0 1`, the `CLK` input only needs the rising edge (don't recommend a `SINE`, it goes smooth but the outout edges suffer).